# How to split data (raw text) into test/train sets with scikit crossvalidation module?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation, text-classification

I have a large corpus of opinions (2500) in raw text. I would like to use scikit-learn library to split them into test/train sets. What could be the best aproach to solve this task with scikit-learn?. Could anybody provide me an example of spliting raw text in test/train sets (probably i´ll use tf-idf representation).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Suppose your data is a list of strings, i.e.

```
data = ["....", "...", ]
```

Then you can split it into training (80%) and test (20%) sets using [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) e.g. by doing:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size = 0.2)
```

Before you rush doing it, though, read [those docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.model_selection) through. 2500 is not a "large corpus" and you probably want to do something like a k-fold cross-validation rather than a single holdout split.

Comment: I would like to do some sentiment analysis in spanish. Is that a correct aproach to split the dataset?, i have a directory with 2500 .txt files (opinions).

Comment: As I said, 2500 is not a large number, so you are better off doing cross-validation to assess your performance. 
Moreover, you might need to first split off a "final test set" (say, 500 items), use the 2000 for model selection (using cross-validation to select the best model), and once you are settled on a model, check its performance on the originally held-out test set.
There may be variations to your approach, depending on a number of factors.